# request for the permission of type system net dnspermission failed

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7.5, asmx, openpop

I have a .net WebService (.asmx) where I use OpenPop library. I try to receive all mails from mailserver and when I make debug from VisualSudio all works fine but when I call the WebService from an android application I receive the error below.
(The WebService in IIS have FULL .Net Trust Level, I added System.Net reference in project...)

> SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring:
>   'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for
>   the permission of type 'System.Net.DnsPermission, System,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.    at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)    at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()    at
>   System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
>   at OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port,
>   Boolean useSsl, Int32 receiveTimeout, Int32 sendTimeout,
>   RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certificateValidator)    at
>   OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port, Boolean
>   useSsl)    at MobileMail.Service1.RefreshMail() in
>   d:\MobileMail\Service1.asmx.cs:line 539

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
            {
              //line 539:
              client.Connect(acc.POP3Server, acc.POP3Port, Convert.ToBoolean(acc.POP3SSL));
             ...
            }
```

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error in this way: "Application Pool" -> "Advanced Settings" of MyWebService under "Process Model", set "Load User Profile" to TRUE